# Factory Design Pattern in Java

Tags: java, beginner, reflection, factory-method

I am currently attempting to understand the fundamentals of factory methods in Java and I found a lot of exampels where a pattern like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162149/factory-design-pattern-with-shapes) has been used.
I got some exercises about sorting algorithms where one task is to write a factory class for all existing algorithms but with the requirement that newly added algorithmes can be integrated via "plug and play". That phrase itched me.By using the `switch case` solution I would be unable to add Algorithms without rewriting the factory class so I came up with this:

**SorterFactory.java**

```
public final class SorterFactory
{

  private SorterFactory()
  {
  }

  public static Sortierer.Sorter getNewSorter( Sorts sorts )
  {
    try
    {
      return (Sortierer.Sorter) Class.forName( sorts.getName() ).getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
    catch ( ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
        | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
        | SecurityException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      // further exception handling
    }
  }
}
```

**Sorts.java**

```
public final class Sorts
{

  private String name;

  // hardcoded for test purpose.
  // will be imported from XML-file
  public static final Sorts HEAPSORT = new Sorts( HeapSort.class.getName() );
  public static final Sorts MERGESORT = new Sorts( MergeSort.class.getName() );
  public static final Sorts BUBBLESORT = new Sorts( BubbleSort.class.getName() );
  public static final Sorts INSERTSORT = new Sorts( InsertSort.class.getName() );
  public static final Sorts QUICKSORT = new Sorts( QuickSort.class.getName() );
  public static final Sorts TRUEHEAPSORT = new Sorts( TrueHeapSort.class.getName() );

  private Sorts( String name )
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
}
```

So why is the `switch case` approach much more favored above this kind of solution in terms of safety,security and performance? Also is it useful to box the names in a class to prevent the misusage of the factory method instead of allow Strings as arguments?

Thanks for any advice and criticism.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general reflection is slow (relative), makes code harder to understand and near impossible to debug if things go wrong.

So if you already know the exact class it's far better to let the compiler check against typo's for you at compile time.

A second issue is that the way it's written now, you just shifted the problem of "rewriting the factory class" to "rewriting the Sorts class". You can't add any other public constant to that class based on an XML file.

---

This isn't entirely clear from the limited problem statement you've given, but perhaps you've misunderstood what kind of factory they expect.

Another interpretation of [the factory method pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/java-the-factory-pattern) expects you to provide a factory interface. This interface defines one or more methods that create some `Sorter`. That way you can "plug" in any other factory to use a different `Sorter`. (Which, compared to just plugging in a different Sorter directly, is only useful if certain Sorters require something extra to create them. For example an extra input parameter.)

Note that this is still usually defined at compile time.

Comment: Thank you alot, that is excatly the type of feedback I needed. And you are right, I would have to rewrite/recompile the Sorts class in my current implementation. That's why I am currently working on a more dynamic solution.